# Get last duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

My issue is that dupes exist because people make mistakes with our shipping orders and another tracking # is created to fix the order. So I always need to get the last duplicate for an order, so I get the right tracking #.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT OrderNum, TrackingNumber, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, Carrier
FROM FPDWDB1.Ship.dbo.ShippingLog
GROUP BY OrderNum
```

I get the following error:

> Column 'FPDWDB1.Ship.dbo.ShippingLog.TrackingNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If you use group by, all other columns other than the group by need to be used in an aggregate function, i.e. max, avg etc. It sounds like you need a row_number(), is it the CreatedDate that determines the latest record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select OrderNum, TrackingNumber, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, Carrier
FROM (
SELECT OrderNum, TrackingNumber, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, Carrier
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNum ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) rn
FROM FPDWDB1.Ship.dbo.ShippingLog
 ) A Where rn = 1
```

OR

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT OrderNum, TrackingNumber, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, Carrier
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNum ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) rn
FROM FPDWDB1.Ship.dbo.ShippingLog
 )
 Select OrderNum, TrackingNumber, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, Carrier
 FROM A  
 Where rn = 1
```